# Speed problems beamer presentation (post-compilation)

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations

I am running kubuntu 14.04 and pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian).

When including images (jpg,eps,png) into a beamer presentation via `\includegraphics[]{}`, I encountered delays of several seconds when loading the slide during the presentation. This delay occured in all sort of pdf viewers and enviromnents (windows, gnome, kde). Moreover, the delay increased even further when putting the `\includegraphics[]{}` command into a tikzpicture via a node. However, if I just click once backwards and forwards trough the whole presentation, everything runs smoothly. Since I won't be able to do this before the talk, I will have to exclude all the images or find the reason for the delay and eliminate it.

Has anyone an idea what the cause for this delay is.

Comment: I find it is even worse with pictures from `tikz` actually. For included images, the most straightforward option is to reduce the size of the image. Since this is for `beamer` you are probably scaling at least some of the images. Scale them in external programmes before inclusion. If that's not enough, work on ways to make the size of the files smaller e.g. use a lossier format if you can do without the quality. I wonder... I have a vague thought but I'd want an MWE to even think about trying it!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  performance of a PDF reader application